# Memory Limit Hit at WooCommerce Loop (wc_get_products)

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, memory, woocommerce

I am trying to get all woocommerce products (6k+) and check if a keyword exists in title with "wc_get_products" function. I know its a big query so i thought i could limit the "wc_get_products" function and loop it to get all products, but still i am getting a php memory limit

my code:

```
// get the total number of products

$total_products = wp_count_posts( 'product' )->publish;

// divide total number of products with the limit 250 and loop it for this times

for ($i=0; $i < $total_products / 250; $i++) {

    $the_products = wc_get_products(
        array(
            'status' => array(
                'publish'
            ),
            'limit' => 250,
            'page' => $i+1
        )
    );

    foreach ($the_products as $products => $product) {

        if (strpos($product->get_name(), 'keyword') !== false) {
            // do something
        }

    }

}
```

any idea why the php memory limit hits no matter how i decrease the loop limit? thanks

Comment: You can use SQL for substring search, so you don't need to load everything from the database. If you like PHP solutions, you may also get pointer to database result and iterate products one by one without storing them all in the array together.

Comment: @user1597430 thanks for your comment! its hard to me to understand why i am getting php momory limit, when the array in every loop has only 250 products. PHP does not clear the previous array every time the loop starts?

Comment: Just curious as to why you want to load all 6K products into an array when you're only interested in the products that have a certain keyword in the product title? You best solution is to tag the products and filter the query .... See: [link]https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/managing-product-taxonomies/

Comment: @Jamie_D hello there! A workaround like this can work but if the number of tagged products reaches the 6k+ in future, i will have the same problem? Thanks

Comment: You should try to use WC's built-in functions if that's the case: [link]https://cfxdesign.com/create-a-custom-woocommerce-product-loop-the-right-way/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today so I've started looking through the Woocomerce code.

function wc_get_products calls

```
      update_post_caches( $query->posts, array( 'product', 'product_variation' ) );
```

after every product query.

If you want to save memory you can clear the WP post cache using

```
      wp_cache_flush();
```

after every iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

The object cache stores each product in memory, which is causing the memory leak and the issue you're experiencing

You should call

```php
wp_suspend_cache_addition(true);
```

before your loop and

```php
wp_suspend_cache_addition(false);
```

after to temporarily disable caching